# Parsing html code with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design-lite

I'm using the new [material-design-lite](http://getmdl.io) (mdl) on my website. I'm also loading in dynamic content using [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

Now, the newly created elements need to be registered with using the `upgradeElement` function for mdl to know of them and apply the javascript to them. On their website they have some [sample code](http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html) to do this:

```
<div id="container"/>
<script>
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var textNode = document.createTextNode('Click Me!');
  button.appendChild(textNode);
  button.className = 'mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect';
  componentHandler.upgradeElement(button);
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
</script>
```

However, I am using jQuery and I'm not entirely sure how I should parse the whole template I get from `mustache.js` and register each component correctly. This is what I've tried:

```
var filledTemplate = '
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
       <div class="mdl-card__title">
           <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Title</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
               <p>A simple paragraph with below some radio buttons</p>
               <p>
                   <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="input_0">
                       <input type="radio" id="input_0" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="radio1" />
                       <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio button 1</span>
                   </label>
               </p>
               <p>
                   <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="input_1">
                       <input type="radio" id="input_1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="radio2" />
                       <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio button 2</span>
                   </label>
               </p>
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
           <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
               Send
           </a>
       </div>
   </div>';

var html = $.parseHTML(filledTemplate);
$(html).find(".mdl-js-button").each(function(){
    componentHandler.upgradeElement($(this));
});
```

The `filledTemplate` is just to give a clear idea of the stuff it can contain. I need to bind all input's, textareas, sliders, radios, checkboxes and a button. In the example above you can see a simple card-layout from mdl, with two radio boxes and a button.

I tried to get the componentHandler to upgrade the button-element first, but mdl returns `element.getAttribute is not a function`, so I guess I'm just giving the wrong value to `.upgradeElement()`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a codepen as an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdByGZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `componentHandler.upgradeElement(this, 'MaterialButton');` if you want just to update the button or `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` to update all elements.

http://jsbin.com/tuluda/4/edit?js,output

Comment: show me how you are attaching the callback to the event

Comment: I don't understand ... the link above seem to work just fine ... the content is appended to the body on click ... am I missing something?

Comment: The issue is that the elements aren't registered properly with mdl. The radio buttons aren't styled, and the button doesn't have the ripple to it. See my original example from my question to see how it should look.

Comment: now I undestand ... updated the answer ... here is the code http://jsbin.com/tuluda/4/edit?js,output

Comment: Thank you very much! So simple... Sorry if my question was somewhat unclear!

Answer (score 0):

I have structured my app as a general container and a set of views, loaded with jQuery and rendered with Hogan. I am invoking `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` after inserting templates and is seems to work fine.

I guess this might be optimized further, upgrading on a smaller granularity, but this simple minded approach works fine in my Phonegap application.
The variables tmpl and content are there to ease debugging, otherwise the code might be made more compact.

```
app.render = function(template, data, destination) {
  $.get(template, function(html) {
    var tmpl = Hogan.compile(html);
    var content = tmpl.render(data);
    $(destination).html(content);
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  });
};
```